# How to stack divs on top of each other? Position absolute isn't working

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I'm using flexbox to create the grid unfortunately, I'm a little stuck as to how to make the divs stack on top of each other. This is what it looks like when I hide overflow:auto and add position relative to the carddiv. I believe the divs are stacking on top but they don't look the right way.

this is what it looks like:

Image Link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIMpt.jpg

What I want it to look like is this:

Except positon:absolute makes everything disappear. 
I'm new to css/html so I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/doyLK.jpg

App.css

```
* {
    /*overflow:auto*/
}

.App {
  /*display: flex;*/
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
}
```

Card.css

```
.container{
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% 10% 10%;
}

.cardDiv {
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
}

.cardPicture {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50vh;
}

.cardDescription {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50vh;
}
```

However, without position:absolute it looks like this which is what I want it to look like except it doesn't stack. I assume the first version is stacked which is why it only shows one div?

The code below is for the second image link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/doyLK.jpg

App.css

```
* {
    overflow:auto
}

.App {
  /*display: flex;*/
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
}
```

Card.css

```
.container{
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% 10% 10%;
}

.cardDiv {
    height: 100vh;
}

.cardPicture {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50vh;
}

.cardDescription {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50vh;
}
```

The cardDivs are being generated through a map function that is inserting the divs.

The html looks like this:

```
<div className='container'>
   <div className="cardDiv">
      <div className="cardPicture"></div>
      <div className="cardDescription"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea on what I could do make the divs stack up without disappearing?

Comment: Try using display: block instead.

Comment: So if I hide overflow:auto, remove flexbox and add display:block and add position:absolute to the cardDiv, it results in the same thing as the first image here:  https://imgur.com/a/1KsJDh7.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the combination of a flex container and flex items that have been set to absolute positioning. When you set `position: absolute` on `.cardDiv` it takes all the cardDiv elements out of the flex flow, and without any width or content, the cardDiv's disappear. As an experiment, take your first CSS block and add a width (say, 50px) to `.cardDiv`. You should see the cards reappear, stacked and taking up 50 pixels horizontally.

When you set a element to `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`, all the direct children of that element become flex items. You can see [all the things that does to the children by default here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#The_flex_container), and the purpose of the various flex properties are there to manipulate how the children will be displayed along the axis you specify. If you set one of these flex-items to absolute positioning, however, [it takes that element out of that flex configuration](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items).

If I understand what you want correctly, I'm not sure you need the container to be flex at all. Try taking the flex properties out of the container, setting the cardDivs to `position:absolute` and setting width and height to conform to how much of the screen you want filled.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1rem;
}

.cardDiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.cardPicture {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50%;
}

.cardDescription {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Let me know if this is not what you were looking for-- I figure you can adjust it to how you want the cards to appear. But that's them stacked and split 50-50 between picture and description.